# python3: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
node2vec = {}
f = open('embed_hep.txt', 'rb')
for i, j in enumerate(f):  # i:index j:item
    if j != '\n':
        node2vec[i] = map(float, j.strip().decode("utf-8").split(' '))
f1 = open('test_graph.txt', 'rb')
edges = [map(int, i.strip().decode("utf-8").split('\t')) for i in f1]
nodes = list(set([i for j in edges for i in j]))
a = 0
b = 0
for i, j in edges:
    if i in node2vec.keys() and j in node2vec.keys():
        dot1 = np.dot(node2vec[i], node2vec[j])
        random_node = random.sample(nodes, 1)[0]
        while random_node == j or random_node not in node2vec.keys():
            random_node = random.sample(nodes, 1)[0]
        dot2 = np.dot(node2vec[i], node2vec[random_node])
        if dot1 > dot2:
            a += 1
        elif dot1 == dot2:
            a += 0.5
        b += 1

print(float(a) / b)
```

this is error:
line 14, in

```
for i, j in edges:
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

embed_hep.txt:

```
1 3 6 8
3 5 7 0
3 6 8 9
```

text_graph.txt:

```
1698    2012
779     778
804     815
```

Comment: Presumably something in edges is empty. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: embed_hep.txt is above ,it is not empty

Comment: No need to use `map` and list comprehensions together. What you're getting is a list of map objects. Try printing out the `edges` before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to convert the map as was suggested above. Next, the error becomes pretty trivial. Your list edges is a list of lists. Hence, you are asking it to unpack to values which it doesn't  have.

```
node2vec = {}
with open('embed_hep.txt') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        nodes  = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]
        node2vec[idx] = nodes

with open('test_graph.txt') as f:
    edges = [[int(j) for j in i.strip().split()] for i in f]
nodes = list(set([i for j in edges for i in j]))

for i, j in edges:
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: can you add the other file because your example is not complete

Comment: OK ,I have add all file

Comment: ok thanks. What do these files represent? I am trying to piece together how node2vec is relevant for the computation below as the idx don't occur in the nodes list. Hence the if is never executed.

Comment: edited the comment above maybe this provides you some clarity

Answer (score 0):

map returns a generator not a list.

Your line

```
edges = [map(int, i.strip().decode("utf-8").split('\t')) for i in f1]
```

should be

```
edges = list(map(int, i.strip().decode("utf-8").split('\t')) for i in f1)
```